# DateTime error resolve with linq

Tags: asp.net, linq, datetime

How can I do this with Linq?
 I've tried without success

```
protected void Calendar1_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataView view = socialEvents.DefaultView;
    view.RowFilter = String.Format(
                      "Date >= #{0}# AND Date < #{1}#",
                      Calendar1.SelectedDate.ToShortDateString(),
                      Calendar1.SelectedDate.AddDays(1).ToShortDateString()
                   );

    if (view.Count > 0)
    {
        DataGrid1.Visible = true;
        DataGrid1.DataSource = view;
        DataGrid1.DataBind();
    }
    else
    {
        DataGrid1.Visible = false;
    }
}
```

I try this but it doen't work

> SyntaxErrorException was unhandled by user code   The expression
>   contains an invalid name: [].

Another try

```
var rows =  socialEvents.Rows.Cast<DataRow>()
            .Where(r => (DateTime)r["Date"] >= Calendar1.SelectedDate.Date &&
                        (DateTime)r["Date"] <= Calendar1.SelectedDate.AddDays(1))
              .ToArray();
view.RowFilter = rows.ToString();
```

Comment: tried Convert.ToDateTime(r["Date"]) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you should use `RowFilter`:

```
view.RowFilter = String.Format(
                  "Date >= #{0}# AND Date < #{1}#",
                  Calendar1.SelectedDate.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"),
                  Calendar1.SelectedDate.AddDays(1).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"));
```

Or with LINQ

```
var table = (from r in socialEvents.AsEnumerable()
             where r.Field<DateTime>("Date") >= Calendar1.SelectedDate.Date
                   r.Field<DateTime>("Date") <= Calendar1.SelectedDate.AddDays(1)
             select r).CopyToDataTable();  

if (table.Rows.Count > 0)
{
    DataGrid1.Visible = true;
    DataGrid1.DataSource = table;
    DataGrid1.DataBind();
}
else
{
    DataGrid1.Visible = false;
}
```

Comment: @user2046944 what means *doesn't work*? Exception? Which exception?

Comment: view.RowFilter = rows;
Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.data.enumerableRowCollection<system.data.datarow>' to 'string'

Comment: @user2046944 `RowFilter` is a string. Why are you assigning rows to string?